# Licence plate detection with different backgrounds

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I just studied the Algorithm of ANPR (Automatic Number Plate Recognition) from the chp 5 of book `Packtpub.Mastering.OpenCV.with.Practical.Computer.Vision.Projects` in which they detect the vehicle licence plate , but their are some restriction in that algorithm , i call it restriction because its specific for one country and can not be used in my country , well in that algorithm they use the following algorithms to detect the licence plate area

```
Sobel filter
Threshold operation (otsu)
Close Morphological operation
Mask of one filled area
Svm classifier
```

But the thing they used is the background color of licence plate as their keypoint for the recognition and detection , but in my area licence plate have different backgrounds , most common are `black , white and green` , green is not much common but rarely used , black background used white number and white contain black numbers , they use floodfill algorithm for white background , but what should i use for 2 different backgrounds ?

```
Is this matter from how much distance you take the image ? 
What is the height and width of licence plate ? 
What are the height and width of characters on the plate ?
What are the distances between the characters ?
```

Comment: Is your starting image already zoomed into the license plate?

Comment: @SamyBencherif Yes , the images on which i train my data is zoomed , and i also want to predict it from the zoomed data , but is this matter from where you take the image ? what is the height -width of licence plate ? what are the height-width of characters on the plate ?

Comment: @SamyBencherif :I could understand only the matter of colour, but your questions at the last,are not so clear.
I suggest for green background, to split the image into R, G and B channels, then to analyse the green one, It should be very so clear. Where in case of B/W plates, you will have the mostly same values in all 3 channels.